# How to select dependent dropdown in edit mode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dropdown

I facing a problem while updating a form. in this form, I fetch the result from DB and display values. there is city and locality dependent dropdown. I fetch the city compare and selected value display but same way dependent dropdown mean locality dropdown doesn't populate. see the Code.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="enq_city">City<span class="red">*</span></label>
    <?php if (isset($cities) && !empty($cities)) { ?>

            <select required="" class="form-control" id="enq_city" name="enq_city">
                <option value="">Choose City</option>
                   <?php foreach ($cities as $city) { 
                       if($city->city_id == $result[0]->enq_city) {
                           $selected = "selected";?>

                <option <?php echo $selected ?> value="<?php echo $city->city_id; ?>">
<?php echo $city->city_name; ?></option>                
                    <?php } ?>       
                    <?php } ?>       
            </select>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="enq_locality">Locality<span class="red">*</span></label>
    <select required="" class="form-control" id="enq_locality" name="enq_locality">

    </select>
</div>
```

My Ajax Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('select[name="enq_city"]').on('change', function() {
        var cityId = $(this).val();
        alert(cityId);
        if(cityId) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getLocality/'+cityId,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                    $('select[name="enq_locality"]').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('select[name="enq_locality"]').append('<option value="'+ value.locality_id +'">'+ value.locality_name +'</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('select[name="enq_locality"]').append('<option value="">No Locality Found</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Does your JS code get executed at all? Have you checked the browsers console (under development tools) for errors? Have you checked the browsers network tab (also under development tools) if the request was made, if it looks correct and that it returns what you expect? Where is your PHP code that suppose to fetch the data from the database? Start by doing some proper debugging and let us know your findings.

Comment: Actually i not too much familier in JS or jquery... thatswhy i am unable to find out the problem. in simple word city fetch from DB but after fetch city its id went to ajax & it display to locality it works fine in Add form but not in edit form

Comment: Unfortunately, without the answers to the questions above, there isn't much we can do other than guessing. Here on SO, you are required to at least do some basic debugging yourself before asking since we're 100% dependent on the information we get from you. We can't possibly know what happens with your code when you run it.

Comment: If you don't know how to use the tools that Magnus outlined above then now is the time to take some time to learn about them. You'll have much more success in creating browser-based applications if you do so. Your browser is practically a fully fledged IDE under the hood...use the tools available. Just saying it doesn't work and you don't know what is happening is not sufficient. You have the tools available to investigate properly, so please use them. We cannot run your code so we can't help you unless you provide some more specific information about your situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand in your question, it seems that you are refreshing this page in some fashion (for 'edit') and pulling data from the database and expecting to make the values appear from the load.

If that is the case, then the reason you are not seeing anything on loading the page is because you are only loading the data "on change" of the select - and as the page is being loaded, there is no 'change' - it is just loaded, so the JS never fires.

One simple way to get that data on loading is to modify your JS a bit.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // pull the AJAX out to a function that can be used later
    function call_ajax(cityId){
         if(cityId){
             $.ajax({
                url: 'getLocality/'+cityId,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                    $('select[name="enq_locality"]').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('select[name="enq_locality"]').append('<option value="'+ value.locality_id +'">'+ value.locality_name +'</option>');
                    });
                }
             });
         }else{
             $('select[name="enq_locality"]').append('<option value="">No Locality Found</option>');
         }
    }

    $('select[name="enq_city"]').on('change', function() {
        var cityId = $(this).val();
        alert(cityId);
        call_ajax(cityId);
    });
    // now, we make sure that 'enq_locality' is populated on loading the page
    // NOTE:  this presumes that $city->city_id exists 
    // from the example code it is also presumed so not checked here
    call_ajax("<?php echo $city->city_id; ?>"); 
});
```

The code is untested (as you didn't give a full example to test.....) though should give some ideas on at least one way to get the data on page load.

If I didn't understand the issue, please give more code and more description of exactly what it happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot CFP... you make my day
approx you did what i want. rest of things i have done.. Thanks again